# How to have slightly different configs for replications of a docker service

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a docker service and I scale it to 3. How can I make sure each of these replications have a slightly different config (for example just a change in one parameter)?

Answer (score 1):

Create another service that does nothing more than exposing a single REST API endpoint where the containers in the replicated service can get their configuration file. Add a curl/wget to the startup script of the service. I can recommend Python + Flask, the API will require not more than a few lines of code.

I think that would be the easiest solution I can think of without relying on something like service discovery with Consul.